# initialisation point of template static member

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

When a class template has a static member, we need an additional (templated) definition of that member. Now, that definition is actually not instantiated right away, rather, the enclosing template need to be instantiated, and the static field need to be "odr-used". So far so good.

However, I get surprising behaviour with GCC / Linux. (g++ **4.7** and **7.2**)

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T>
class Factory
  {
  public:
    T val;

    Factory()
      : val{}
      {
        cout << "Factory-ctor  val="<<val<<endl;
      }
  };


template<typename T>
class Front
  {
  public:
    static Factory<T> fac;

    Front()
      {
        cout << "Front-ctor    val="<<fac.val<<endl;
        fac.val += 100;
      }

    T&
    operate ()
      {
        cout << "Front-operate val="<<fac.val<<endl;
        ++ fac.val;
        return fac.val;
      }
  };

template<typename T>
Factory<T> Front<T>::fac;


namespace {
  Front<int> front;
  int global_int = front.operate();
}



int
main (int, char**)
  {
    Front<int> fint;

    int& i = fint.operate();
    cout << "main:         val="<<i<<endl;
    cout << "global_int.......="<<global_int<<endl;

    return 0;
  }
```

In the anonymous namespace, we first create a static instance of Front and then we invoke the `operate()` function on it, which *uses* the static factory member. Both output and values clearly indicate that the static member's ctor is invoked *after* it has been used. What could be the reasoning behind such behaviour? It seems counter intuitive for me: assumed the factory manages some resource, the resource would be leaked.

```
~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0

~$ g++ --std=gnu++17 demo.cpp -o demo
~$ ./demo
Front-ctor    val=0
Front-operate val=100
Factory-ctor  val=0
Front-ctor    val=0
Front-operate val=100
main:         val=101
global_int.......=101
```

I tried also Clang (3.5), which just segfaults.

---

**PS**: the obvious workaround is to turn the factory into a Meyers Singleton. Yet I'd expect the system of ctors and dtors to be airtight in such a basic situation (note we aren't referring to any static from other translation units). Thus I am primarily interested in the *reasoning* explaining that observation.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually referred to, rather appropriately, as the static initialization order fiasco.

Basically, we have three objects with static storage duration: `front`, `global_int`, and `Front<int>::fac`. We have, from [basic.start.dynamic](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic):

> Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is unordered if the variable is an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, is partially-ordered if the variable is an inline variable that is not an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, and otherwise is ordered.

So `Front<int>::fac` is unordered, the other two are ordered. We know `front` is initialized before `global_int`, because they're sequenced in definition order. But `Front<int>::fac` is indeterminately sequenced with the other two.

Basically what's happening is that static initialization happens first (which zero-initializes), and then, sometime later, your `Factory` constructor actually runs - sometime after you actually want it to.

One thing you *could* do is force the initialization of your `Factory` to be *constant initialization* - which moves it ahead of dynamic initialization. You can do that by just marking your constructor `constexpr`.

Alternatively, you could wrap your `static` into a function as per the Meyers singleton.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I know the "static init order fiasco" with serveral *.cpp translation units; and there it kind-of seems to be logical (yet unfortunate). But here we have a _single_ translation unit. What actual problem prevents the compiler from just doing the right thing here? What benefit does the language win from having a templated static variable behave deliberately different than a normal static variable?

Comment: @Ichthyo One question might be: what would the ordering be bewteen `Front<T>::fac` and `Front<U>::fac`?

Comment: good point. But that does not preclude them both to be emitted prior to any expression within _the same translation unit_ using them.

Comment: @Ichthyo If I were to instantiate `Front<T>::fac` before `Front<U>::fac` in one TU, and `Front<U>::fac` before `Front<T>::fac`in another, which order should the final executable respect?

Comment: you are overlooking the elephant in the room: it is darn much irrelevant how T and U are ordered relative to each other, as long as `Front<T>::fac` is initialised _prior to being used_ for the first time in the whole program, and same for `Front<T>::fac`. Because, if the Factory is already used and then initialised, it will leak the resources it manages.

Comment: @Ichthyo How would you ensure that happens? Add a check on each access?

Comment: @Barry (1) in each translation unit, emit the code for the initialiser at suitable scope **prior** to the first expression causing the intstantiation of the templated static field. (2) let the linker use the first initialiser _in the static initialisation order created by the linker_ and discard all further ones. Note: this is _almost entirely_ what the GCC / Clang compiler and linker does right now, just they "happily" (lazily?) drop off the code for the initialiser _after_ the expression causing the template instantiation.

Comment: Btw, I am inferring that behaviour from observed behaviour of test programs and from looking at the generated object file's headers. I do not know the source/implementation internals of the compiler

Comment: ... with "drop off" I mean the following: from a high-level viewpoint, each translation unit generates a ordered chain of static initialisers. The linker picks those chains and combines them in one

Comment: @Ichthyo (1) How do you know which is the "first expression causing the instantiation"? You're making this out like it's a trivial problem and nobody cares about it. I think it's much more difficult than you're giving it credit for being.

Comment: Then please enlighten me! I can not see the problem, honestly.

Comment: Regarding static initialisation, a compiler treats each translation unit top down. Whenever he encounters something which needs dynamic initialisation code, he hooks it up into the chain, which the runtime system invokes prior to main(). For that reason, _normal_ (non template) static intialisers are completely deterministic (within a single translation unit). Moreover, the compiler is able to drop off the initialiser for a templated static on demand (i.e. at the point where the fist odr-use happens, in source code order). Thus "fist encounter" is absolutely well defined.

Comment: So what I do not understand: for a non templated static init, the compiler is able to inject it before the ctor call. Why isn't he able to do the same for a templated one? Do you know the reason?